# Spawning an image and making it move with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, move

I am trying to get a bullet spawned and moving. I get it spawned with no problem, but it is not moving.

Javascript:

```
var index = 0;

var timer_id; // reference of the timer, needed to stop it
var speed = 350; // pixels/second
var period = 10; // milliseconds
var sprite; // the element that will move
var sprite_speed = 0; // move per period
var sprite_position = 315; // pixels


document.getElementById('jack').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "images/bullet.png";
  img.id = "bullet" + index;
  img.name = "bullet" + index;
  img.setAttribute("style", "position:relative;");
  var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
  foo.appendChild(img);

  move("bullet" + index);

  index++;
});


if (document.images) {
  var image1 = new Image();
  image1.src = "/images/jack01.png";
  var image2 = new Image();
  image2.src = "/images/jack02.png";
}
```

HTML

```
<a onmousedown="document.jack.src=image2.src;" onmouseup="document.jack.src=image1.src;">Spawn a bullet</a>
```

CSS

```
#bullet { 
  position: fixed;
  position: absolute;
  top: 750px;
  left: 500px;
}

#foobar {
  position: relative;
}
```

So that code above does make a bullet spawn, but it does not make it move!

Comment: You named the bullet wrong, it's *Bullet Bill*. But where (or what does) is the function `move` you invoke?

Comment: I don't have it. I tried several methods and none worked.

Answer (score 0):

For the animation you would need a loop. You could check out my [game loop](https://github.com/jacksonv1lle/LoopJS) code - maybe it would be of some use.

Each loop object has an update() and render() function which are called as the loop runs.

You can place your update code inside the update function. ie. increment the bullet position

Then you can use the render function to apply the position value to the bullet image